# Missing concrete implementation of 'State.build'

Tags: flutter, dart, cross-platform

I am in the learning stage of flutter and facing errors. I am watching a course on Udemy. I am trying to build a Personal Expense Tracker. It's a fundamental project but, as I already told I am currently learning and am facing an error. Any help would be appreciated.
This is the code of my main.dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './widgets/transaction_list.dart';
import './widgets/new_transactions.dart';
import './widgets/chart.dart';
import './models/transaction.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData theme = ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.primaries[1],
      errorColor: Colors.red,
      fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
    );
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Expense Planner',
      theme: theme.copyWith(
        colorScheme: theme.colorScheme.copyWith(secondary: Colors.amber),
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final List<Transaction> _userTransactions = [];

  List<Transaction> get _recentTransactions {
    return _userTransactions.where((tx) {
      return tx.date.isAfter(
        DateTime.now().subtract(
          Duration(days: 7),
        ),
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  void _addNewTransaction(
      String txTitle, double txAmount, DateTime chosenDate) {
    final newTx = Transaction(
      title: txTitle,
      amount: txAmount,
      date: chosenDate,
      id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    );

    setState(() {
      _userTransactions.add(newTx);
    });
  }

  void _startAddNewTransaction(BuildContext ctx) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: ctx,
      builder: (_) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {},
          child: NewTransaction(_addNewTransaction),
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _deleteTransaction(String id) {
    setState(() {
      _userTransactions.removeWhere((tx) => tx.id == id);
      {
        ;
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(
              'Expense Planner',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                fontSize: 22,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                onPressed: () => _startAddNewTransaction(context),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                Chart(_recentTransactions),
                TransactionList(_userTransactions, _deleteTransaction),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          floatingActionButtonLocation:
              FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () => _startAddNewTransaction(context),
          ),
        );
      }
    });
  }
}
```

There's some error in the _MyHomePageState class. it shows the following error

```
Missing concrete implementation of 'State.build'.
Try implementing the missing method, or make the class abstract.
```

However when I try to make the _MyHomePageState class abstract it shows the following:

```
Abstract classes can't be instantiated.
Try creating an instance of a concrete subtype.
```

Thanks & Regards,
Harshit Chitkara

Answer (score 0):

I think 'home: MyHomePage(),' is waiting for a Widget. You have to build a Widget arround the List. After that you probably need a Scaffold inside the Widget.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       child: List<Transaction> get _recentTransactions {
      return _userTransactions.where((tx) {
        return tx.date.isAfter(
          DateTime.now().subtract(
            Duration(days: 7),
          ),
        );
      }).toList();
    }
    );
  }
```

This should fix the current problem, but you can't have a return inside a return.